# AppleScript to move folder contents to another computer

Tags: applescript, workflow, automator

I have never written AppleScript in my life (a few Powershell and batch files for work, but I am by no means an expert on those even). I've used automator before to do similar things, but the program I need to have run the command only accepts AppleScript.

I need an apple script that can do the following

1. Mount an network share (windows machine network share, if that
   matters, username and password are stored in Keychain)
2. Move (NOT copy) all the contents from a folder on my MacBook to that share
3. Unmount that share.

Alternatively, I have this already in a workflow, so if there is a way to convert/export/whatever a workflow into an AppleScript, that would be awesome too!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have it in an _Automator_ workflow, convert that workflow into a **service** or an **application**.  The first will let you assign a keyboard shortcut to activate it simply by a hotkey; the second will let you launch the application, which can be done by any script.  In AppleScript, it would look like `tell application "%appname%" to activate` (where `%appname%` is the name of the application you create with _Automator_).

Comment: [Read this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/MakeaSystem-WideService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH46-SW1) for more information.

Comment: I think that will work. Thanks!